# Prevent flutter from rebuild the page when using PageRouteBuilder

Tags: flutter, rebuild

Every time the PageRouteBuilder is called the current Page is rebuild and during transition of the route the initial page is shown. Instead the route should not be rebuild and the current context of the page should be shown during transition.

Code of the PageRouteBuilder

```
class RouteChange extends PageRouteBuilder {


  final Widget enterPage;
  final Widget exitPage;
  final Offset beginOffsetExit;
  final Offset endOffsetExit;
  final Offset beginOffsetEnter;
  final Offset endOffsetEnter;
  final Offset beginOffsetButton;
  final Offset endOffsetButton;
  final Widget animatedWidget;

  RouteChange({
    required this.exitPage,
    required this.enterPage,
    required this.beginOffsetExit,
    required this.endOffsetExit,
    required this.beginOffsetEnter,
    required this.endOffsetEnter,
    required this.beginOffsetButton,
    required this.endOffsetButton,
    required this.animatedWidget,
  }) : super(
          transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
          pageBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
          ) {
            return enterPage;
          },
          transitionsBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
            Widget child,
          ) {
            return Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                SlideTransition(
                  position: Tween<Offset>(
                    begin: beginOffsetExit, //const Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                    end: endOffsetExit, //const Offset(0.0, -1.0),
                  ).animate(
                    CurvedAnimation(
                      parent: animation,
                      curve: Curves.linearToEaseOut,
                      reverseCurve: Curves.easeInToLinear,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: exitPage,
                ),
                SlideTransition(
                  position: Tween<Offset>(
                    begin: beginOffsetEnter, //const Offset(0.0, 1.0),
                    end: endOffsetEnter, // constOffset(0.0, 0.0),
                  ).animate(
                    CurvedAnimation(
                      parent: animation,
                      curve: Curves.linearToEaseOut,
                      reverseCurve: Curves.easeInToLinear,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: enterPage,
                ),
                SlideTransition(
                  position: Tween<Offset>(
                          begin: beginOffsetButton, //const Offset(-0.215, 0.4),
                          end: endOffsetButton //const Offset(-0.215, -0.45),
                          )
                      .animate(
                    CurvedAnimation(
                      parent: animation,
                      curve: Curves.linearToEaseOut,
                      reverseCurve: Curves.easeInToLinear,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: animatedWidget,
                )
              ],
            );
          },
        );
}
```

I tried with keepAlive but it doesn't worked. Maybe I placed it in the wrong place.